# Java Virtual Machine crashes Multiple times

Tags: java, crash, runtime-error

This is the entire error message

http://pastebin.com/bDgye0rt

The error log is too big that I can't attach it here. I am not extremely familiar with how jvm works in the background and what registers it makes use of. I am hoping someone can look at this error log and explain to me what it means.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ffd18cbcafe, pid=29906, tid=140725158119168
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
# Distribution: Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy), package 6b27-1.12.6-1~deb7u1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libresolv.so.2+0x7afe]  __libc_res_nquery+0x19e
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I can't understand why and how it is created. It keeps happening all the time.

PS:
I have the error log of another 3 crashes that happened in my machine which I can share if you think its necessary.

## **EDIT**

I have around 8 logs and out of the 8 logs it is made clear that the last call before the program crashes is

```
java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr
```

I do not believe the input is that much related because there is a static list of inputs that are parsed serially, and the error occurs at different time frames (Sometimes 1 hour after the program has been running and some other times 6 hours, it appears to be random).

Comment: You using JNI? Calling some native code?

Comment: Boris might have it. The key part to see is `The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code` line towards the bottom of the error you posted here.

Comment: @Boris the Spider I don't use JNI in my program but maybe one of the libraries I use does that.

Comment: From the java stack we see java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Ljava/lang/String;)  call the glibc method __libc_res_nquery. What kind of hostname give you to HttpURLConnection ?

Comment: @mpromonet It is something I don't know. It is a hostname from a big list of host names.

Comment: Did you try with an other jvm than the openJDK one ?

Comment: @mpromonet I am not sure if that would help I will try it later on and let you know.

Comment: Are there any other suggestions of what I Should try or what might cause the problem? Could it be a bug?

Comment: Can you paste the code related to your ipv6 address. I found some where that, it is bug in ipv6 classes

Comment: @Optimus I invoke   InetSocketAddress proxyConnection = new InetSocketAddress(
    inputProxy.IP, inputProxy.Port);
InetSocketAddress proxyConnection = new InetSocketAddress(
    inputProxy.IP, inputProxy.Port);
  Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxyConnection);

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue related to glibc and IPv6.

It would be safe to add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to ask JVM use IPv4 first to avoid this issue.